# Matlab MIDI send message problem, not hearing the output

Tags: matlab, midi

I"m trying to get Matlab to send MIDI messages to my keyboard but I am not hearing anything. I can receive into Matlab just fine using midireceive. Here's the code...

```
mididevinfo;
%   MIDI devices available:
%   ID  Direction  Interface   Name
%    0    input    CoreMIDI   'USB Keystation 88es'
%    1   output    CoreMIDI   'USB Keystation 88es'

device = mididevice('USB Keystation 88es');

msgs = midimsg('Note',1,48,64,0.25);
midisend(device,msgs);
```

Comment: Does it work if you use mididevice(1) instead?